# Can I use variable substitution with ansible-galaxy and requirements.yml?

Tags: bash, ansible, yaml, substitution

We have private git repos for a number of Ansible roles. The repo hosts vary from site to site, for example:

- Site1 uses `https://gitforsite1.ourdomain.com`
- Site2 uses `https://gitforsite2.ourdomain.com`

What I want is to have a single `requirements.yml` file and substitute the correct git repo. One way I could do this is to have a bash script set an environment variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
if [ "$1" = "site1" ]; then
    export REPO_ROOT="https://gitforsite1.ourdomain.com"
fi
if [ "$1" = "site2" ]; then
    export REPO_ROOT="https://gitforsite2.ourdomain.com"
fi
... error checking if the value is not site1 or site2 ...
# Then install the roles
ansible-galaxy install -f -r config/requirements.yml -p roles
```

and then substitute this value in `requirements.yml`:

```
---

- src: {{ lookup('env', 'REPO_ROOT') }}/role1.git
  name: role1

- src: {{ lookup('env', 'REPO_ROOT') }}/role.git
  name: role2
```

This approach gives: `ERROR! Unable to load data from the requirements file` suggesting that the file structure is incorrect. (It may be that the approach works and I've got the syntax wrong.)

Any approach that lets me set a variable (environment, command line, whatever) is fine. Alternatively, if this is not supported, do I need to rewrite the `requirements.yml` file at runtime, maybe using `sed`?

**EDIT 1:**
Added the `ansible-galaxy` line in the bash script excerpt above to show how the `requirements.yml` file is being used. I think that this is the problem: `ansible-galaxy` is not expanding the variable substitutions, whether included in `group_vars/all` or the environment. Using Ansible version 2.3.1.0 with Python 2.7.10.

**EDIT 2:**
Discovered [in the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#galaxy-settings) there is a `server` option to point to another Galaxy instance, in `ansible.cfg`, like so:

```
[galaxy]  
server=https://gitforsite1.ourdomain.com
```

Galaxy *does* use this setting, *but* it must be a full Galaxy web app, because it calls `https://gitforsite1.ourdomain.com/api`. So that doesn't help me either.

Comment: Why not put `REPO_ROOT` in the `group_vars/all` file of the different site inventories?

Comment: What version of Ansible? 1.4 and later you can use `- src: "{{ ansible_env.REPO_ROOT }}/role1.git"`.

Comment: @Jack Thanks - good idea, but it seems `ansible-galaxy` is ignoring these (see edit to post).

Comment: @Deathgrip I'm calling `ansible-galaxy` directly from the bash script (see edit to post). I don't think it is expanding any substitutions.

Comment: You put `REPO_ROOT` into `group_vars/all`?

Answer (score 2):

When they begin with `{`, you should quote the values in the mappings associated with source. If not the yaml parser will try and parse that value as a flow-style mapping instead of a scalar:

```
- src: "{{ lookup('env', 'REPO_ROOT') }}/role1.git"
  name: role1
```

Since you have single quotes in your scalar and no double quotes, nor any backslashes (`\`), I used double quotes around the scalar. You better use single quotes if you have no single quotes in your scalar or if you have any backslashes. If you have both types of quotes, use single quotes and double any single quotes **within** the scalar. The following will load the same as the above:

```
- src: '{{ lookup(''env'', ''REPO_ROOT'') }}/role1.git'
  name: role1
```

Comment: Thanks - your reformat got me past the yaml parser error (and you're right, the two forms equate to the same result), but the variable substitutions are not being expanded by `ansible-galaxy` (see edit to post).

Answer (score 0):

What if you did it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
if [ "$1" = "site1" ]; then
    export REPO_ROOT="https://gitforsite1.ourdomain.com"
fi
if [ "$1" = "site2" ]; then
    export REPO_ROOT="https://gitforsite2.ourdomain.com"
fi
... error checking if the value is not site1 or site2 ...
# Then install the roles
ansible-galaxy install -f -r config/requirements.yml -p roles -s ${REPO_ROOT}
```

and then substitute this value in requirements.yml:

```
---

- src: role1.git
  name: role1

- src: role.git
  name: role2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround. If you don't mind the execution time, please refer to:

```
- name: geerlingguy.docker
- name: geerlingguy.docker
  src: https://my-private-server-1/path/is/not/important/docker.tar.gz
- name: geerlingguy.docker
  src: https://my-private-server-2/path/is/not/important/docker.tar.gz
```

and execute ansible-galaxy like:

```
$ ansible-galaxy install --ignore-errors -r requirements.git-cache.yml
```

This example achieve that it will install the next same role from if we have internet outage.

Once one of the same role installed, the installation of the same role will be skipped.

Of course, you can change the order of roles what you want.